# How to retrieve some special characters (& ,<) from sql while using AJAX

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am saving user fed text entered in a text box into the database and then retrieving the entered text using `ajax`(using `JavaScript` and not `jQuery`).

All special characters are getting inserted well in mysql but it is not able to  retrieve the data containing special characters. Greater than `(>)` symbol is getting retrieved successfully but `&` and `<` is causing the whole page to load without any result.

**Code for inserting data**:

```
for($i=0;$i<$No_of_Inp_Fields; $i++)
{   

    $Desc = $_POST['txtdesc'.($i).''];

    $inquery="INSERT INTO DETAILS VALUES ('$Desc')";
    $sSql = mysql_query($inquery);

}
```

**Code for retrieving the data**

```
   $queryPopIP=mysql_query("select Desc from DETAILS where Nm='$tag'");
    $resPopIP=mysql_fetch_array($queryPopIP);
    $DesPop=$resPop[0];
```

This is sent as a response using php

**Code for displaying the data(using javascript)**

```
var desIP=serverResponse.split('_');
document.getElementById('popdiv2').innerHTML="<b>"+desIP[1];
```

Comment: What are you doing with the result? If you're trying to just include it in the page directly (without escaping the values) that would explain the problem. We really need to see what you're doing in order to help you. (And presumably you're not getting the data *straight* from the database using AJAX - what server is in the middle?)

Comment: @Jon Skeet I am retrieving the data and displaying it when the user is hovering the mouse over some particular labels. And yes I am using it directly ,without escaping the values)

Comment: Well don't do that then - escape the values so that they're proper HTML. You still haven't shown us any code...

Comment: @ Jon Skeet I have added the codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No jQuery... add the text as a text node.  It'll preserve the angle brackets or other special characters.

```
document.getElementById('someElement').appendChild( document.createTextNode('<b>sushi</b>') );
```

I think this what you are asking?  Honestly still not a 100% clear.

If that's not it, you probably need to call htmlentities on your data (if you are using PHP) when you are displaying the values of your data.

**EDIT**

Since it looks like $DesPop is what you send through AJAX, do this in your PHP

```
$DesPop = htmlentities($resPop[0]);
```